# Ksoap2 is not working in android 3.0 getting NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-strictmode

Ksoap2 is not working in Android 3.0. Logcat shows NetworkOnMainThreadException:

```
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com. Bill/com. Bill.Diag}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1701)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1717)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:984)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3900)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1069)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:368)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:208)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:431)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:901)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:75)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:304)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:46)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:68)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at com.IsBill.Connection.Connect(Connection.java:53)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at com.IsBill.Diagnos.FirstProv(Diagnos.java:385)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at com.IsBill.Diagnos.onCreate(Diagnos.java:53)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1665)
02-24 20:18:34.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821845/honycomb-and-defaulthttpclient) about the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: You could wrap your ksoap call in an AsyncTask. Read [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for more.

Comment: You conclusion that ksoap is not working is wrong. ANY network traffic on the UI thread will show the same behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

StrictMode is enabled in HoneyComb, disable it to avoid [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

**UPDATE:**

other way detecting is strictMode exist using StrictModeWrapper class.

```
 private static boolean strictModeAvailable;

    // use the StrictModeWrapper to see if we are running on Android 2.3 or higher and StrictMode is available
    static {
        try {
            StrictModeWrapper.checkAvailable();
            strictModeAvailable = true;
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            strictModeAvailable = false;
        }
    }
```

StrictModeWrapper Class

```
import android.os.StrictMode;

/**
 * StrictModeWrapper is a wrapper class for the android class android.os.StrictMode provided with Android 2.3 onwards.
 * It allows usage of StrictMode class on devices/emulators with Android 2.3 or higher, while providing an availability
 * check so that the code can stay in situ for lower platform versions. See the application class for usage.
 *
 * @author Manfred Moser <manfred@simpligility.com>
 *
 * @see "http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html"
 * @see "http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html"
 */
public class StrictModeWrapper {

    /* class initialization fails when this throws an exception */
   static {
       try {
           Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode", true, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           throw new RuntimeException(ex);
       }
   }

    /**
     * Check if the class android.os.StrictMode is available at runtime.
     */
   public static void checkAvailable() {}


    /**
     * Call StrictMode.enableDefaults().
     */
    public static void enableDefaults() {
       StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    }

    // all the implementation below is not tested but it should work ... feel free to check and send me fixes..
    public static  void setThreadPolicy(android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    public static  android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy getThreadPolicy() {
        return StrictMode.getThreadPolicy();
    }

    public static  android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy allowThreadDiskWrites() {
        return StrictMode.allowThreadDiskWrites();
    }

    public static  android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy allowThreadDiskReads() {
        return StrictMode.allowThreadDiskReads();
    }

    public static  void setVmPolicy(android.os.StrictMode.VmPolicy policy) {
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(policy);
    }

    public static android.os.StrictMode.VmPolicy getVmPolicy() {
        return StrictMode.getVmPolicy();
    }

    public static final class ThreadPolicyWrapper
    {
        public static final class BuilderWrapper
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder builderInstance;

            public  BuilderWrapper() {
                    builderInstance = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder();
            }

            public  BuilderWrapper(android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy) {
                    builderInstance = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder(policy);
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder detectAll() {
                return builderInstance.detectAll();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder permitAll() {
                return builderInstance.permitAll();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder detectNetwork() {
                return builderInstance.detectNetwork();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder permitNetwork() {
                return builderInstance.permitNetwork();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder detectDiskReads() {
                return builderInstance.detectDiskReads();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder permitDiskReads() {
                return builderInstance.permitDiskReads();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder detectDiskWrites() {
                return builderInstance.detectDiskWrites();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder permitDiskWrites() {
                return builderInstance.permitDiskWrites();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder penaltyDialog() {
                return builderInstance.penaltyDialog();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder penaltyDeath() {
                return builderInstance.penaltyDeath();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder penaltyLog() {
                return builderInstance.penaltyLog();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder penaltyDropBox() {
                return builderInstance.penaltyDropBox();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy build() {
                return builderInstance.build();
            }
        }
    }

    public static final class VmPolicyWrapper {
        public static final class BuilderWrapper {
            private StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builderInstance;

            public BuilderWrapper() {
                builderInstance = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder detectAll() {
                return builderInstance.detectAll();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects() {
                return builderInstance.detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder penaltyDeath() {
                return builderInstance.penaltyDeath();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder penaltyLog() {
                return builderInstance.penaltyLog();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder penaltyDropBox() {
                return builderInstance.penaltyDropBox();
            }

            public android.os.StrictMode.VmPolicy build() {
                return builderInstance.build();
            }
        }
    }
    // add more wrapping as desired..
}
```

Comment: Correct .. and ICS. It will depend if the hardware manufacturer allows that setting. By default they will probably not since thats how it is in upstream. In any case... this is a workaround at best. Just do an asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do any network operation in a separate thread and not on the UI thread. The easiest way to do that is using AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Network operation must handle on new thread to do so
You should call ksoap request in an AsyncTask task class 
in your Asynctask Call your KSOAP reuest in     `doInBackground()` method
e.g.

```
public class Get extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg) {

   //your KSOAP request code
}
```

}