# Is there any thing we have to change in the code when we shift the API levels?

Tags: java, android

I have connected to the web service and retrieved the values in android device, version 2.2, API 8. But when I changed the version to 3.0 and the emulator to API 11. the same code is showing error. I have changed the manifest file sdk versions and all.

The problem is as follows:

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
// androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
try{
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    // after this line it is going to the catch block
    SoapObject resultString=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

    // the result string is null when I used debugger and checked
    System.out.println("the result string displayed :" +resultString);
    String result=resultString.getProperty(0).toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

**The Logcat Error is as follow:**

```
WARN/System.err(886): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 WARN/System.err(886):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
 WARN/System.err(886):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:368)
 WARN/System.err(886):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:208)
 WARN/System.err(886):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:431)
 WARN/System.err(886):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:901)
 WARN/System.err(886):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:75)
WARN/System.err(886):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
WARN/System.err(886):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:304)
WARN/System.err(886):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
WARN/System.err(886):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
WARN/System.err(886):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
WARN/System.err(886):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
WARN/System.err(886):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:75)
WARN/System.err(886):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:136)
WARN/System.err(886):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:90)
WARN/System.err(886):     at com.timetracker.app.Index.run(Index.java:214)
WARN/System.err(886):     at com.timetracker.app.Index$1.onClick(Index.java:77)
WARN/System.err(886):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100)
WARN/System.err(886):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644)
WARN/System.err(886):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
WARN/System.err(886):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
WARN/System.err(886):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
WARN/System.err(886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
WARN/System.err(886):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
WARN/System.err(886):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
WARN/System.err(886):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
WARN/System.err(886):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
WARN/System.err(886):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Add the LogCat output of the Exception...

Comment: "is showing error"? **Which error?** Error messages are **not** just things to be feared. They *provide information*!

Comment: @ Joachim Sauer  it is a warning message, I have edited the post, and I have put the logcat message also.

Comment: what about if you put this stuff or code in separate Thread?

Comment: Looks like you are having the same issue as this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821845/honycomb-and-defaulthttpclient
Pretty much there are new policies in version 3.0 that try to guide you into using async methods if the code may take awhile to execute.

Comment: The code is not executing further for me, it is going to the catch block where the exception is caught and returning null value when it is debugged.

Answer (score 1):

try writing you onCreate this way,

```
public void onCreate() { 
  StrictMode.enableDefaults(); //this line add 
  super.onCreate(); 
  //put your Code
}
```

Tell me if this works..and to read the blog entry go to [this link here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html).