# Exception on httpclient.execute to web server

Tags: android, exception, httpclient

I try to send JSON data on web server and get response by this method.

```
public JSONObject postOnServer(JSONObject json) {

    HttpResponse response;
    JSONObject res = null;

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 10000);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(PATH);

    try {

        //StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity("json", String.valueOf(json));
        ByteArrayEntity postMessage = new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8"));
        httpPost.setEntity(postMessage);
        response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

            InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            try {
                res = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.i("Response JSON", e.toString());
            }

        } else {

            res = new JSONObject();
            try {
                res.put("error", "Unable to load page.");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        Log.i("Connection.postOnServer", "1.try exception: "+ex);
        res = new JSONObject();
        try {
            res.put("error", "Synchronization is not enable: Connection has aborted.");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.i("Connection.postOnServer", "put exception: "+e);
        }

    }

    return res;
}
```

But always it end on line `response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);` with this exception

```
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:138)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-24 10:58:51.635: E/AndroidRuntime(4709):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

Have someone idea, how to fix it? On thirst try if i use catch(IOException), aplication is destroyd. If I use catch(Exception) aplication go on with no action. What should I do to send data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4822122/1251715 same issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [HonyComb and DefaultHttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821845/honycomb-and-defaulthttpclient)

Answer (score 2):

Android doesn't let you run network requests on the user interface thread. This is to stop the requests from jamming up the interface while they execute. You need to execute the request in a separate thread. Here's an example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    //Thread to stop network calls on the UI thread
    public void run() {
        //Request the HTML
        try {
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT_SOCKET);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(getString(R.string.url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            //Do something with the response
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Tag", "Could not get HTML: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: And how I return that response from method where I do it?

Comment: You don't. If you returned a response, it implies that the calling method has to wait for the response so you may as well not Thread it. Any update that needs to happen, you need to do in the Thread doing the network calls.