# Android connection timeout in Unittesting (robolectric)

Tags: android, multithreading, robolectric

I have some problems with my threading. During debug mode and during unittests, the AsyncTask is not executed as a single thread.

Furthermore i get a timeout when i try to test my HTTP-Post to a real server. I got this before in the emulator and it has been solved by

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Unfortunately this does not work on Robolectric because i get an error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dalvik/system/CloseGuard$Reporter
```

how can i solve this problem and continue building my unittests with robolectric? Is it possible that i handled something wrong during threading?
The async task:

```
public class HttpPostTask extends
    AsyncTask<MyContainer, Integer, MyResult> {
    @Override
    protected MyResult doInBackground(MyContainer... params) {
           /* some code here */
           resp = client.execute(container.post);
    }
}
```

executing the async task:

```
new HttpPostTask().execute(container);
```

Thank you

=============== UPDATE ===================
I inserted some prints to figure out on which thread the post runs. These are the results:

in Emulator:

```
09-27 09:19:12.909: I/System.out(1813): Running REST Client on thread 'Thread-83' 
 09-27 09:19:12.909: I/System.out(1813): Running HTTP Post on thread 'AsyncTask #2'
```

in Robolectric:

```
Running REST Client on thread 'main' 
  Running HTTP Post on thread 'main'
```

after a while i get a refused + timeout exception:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:8080 refused
```

To bypass Robolectric's HTTP Post i used this: `'Robolectric.getFakeHttpLayer().interceptHttpRequests(false);'`

Comment: Of course the server is up and running.

Answer (score 4):

**Update** I'm working on an update for Robolectric that will turn some basic `StrictMode` methods into no-ops so it won't blow up a test suite. However, I still think something is wrong if you're app is not functioning without it.

---

A few things here:

#### Task scheduling

Robolectric runs single threaded. It simulates the UI and background loopers and allows you to interact with them in tests using `Robolectric.getUiThreadScheduler()` and `Robolectric.getBackgroundScheduler()`. With the `Scheduler`s you can `pause()`, `unPause()`, `runOneTask()` and more. By default all `AsyncTask`s will run immediately upon `execute()`

#### Testing HTTP Requests

While a full integration test combining Android and the underlying web server is a good idea, most Robolectric tests are more of a unit testing nature. I would recommend using `Robolectric.addPendingHttpRequest()` to provide fake responses for most tests.

#### StrictMode

I don't think this is supported by Robolectric but I haven't investigated. It does not make sense to use based on the Android documentation given that Robolectric is single threaded.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need to do real HTTP Post-tests but i get a timeout without using strict mode. Is there any other way to do real HTTP Posts with robolectric?

Comment: "Android doesn't let you run network requests on the user interface thread. This is to stop the requests from jamming up the interface while they execute. You need to execute the request in a separate thread." I think this is the problem because in the emulator everything works fine.

Comment: source for the cite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734717/exception-on-httpclient-execute-to-web-server

Comment: You should be able to do real HTTP by following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475998/is-it-possible-to-do-real-http-requests-with-robolectric

Comment: I'm not sure why you always get a timeout without `StrictMode` but it seems like a smell that something is running on the UI thread that shouldn't be. Is there any more code you can provide?

Comment: My app is working without StrictMode, but not when it is single-threaded. Perhaps i should have a look at my JSON-post. When will the update be available? How does Robolectric handle the threading to the android.jar?

Comment: Is this a similar problem?: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/robolectric/Z3Yg04gL4hg/iwYlnvHAkO4J

Comment: @CoreyD "By default all AsyncTasks will run immediately upon execute()" is this from the documentation? Can you please give a reference?