# Make HTTP requests with progress bar, before opening a new Activity: how?

Tags: android, eclipse, multithreading, progress-bar

I have a piece of code that sets some network IP cameras parameters by simply calling some URLs. URLs are (to simplify) in this format "http://mydomain.com:portnumber/setalarm.cgi" and I use a normal HttpGet / HttpResponse mechanism to call URL and get result status (200 if it is good, other if bad).
Now: as URL to be called are 8 or more, in sequence (I use for loop), I would like to display a progress bar (or the simple progress indicator) to let the user know that the different URL calls are being performed. When all of the 8 calls are done, I would like a new Actity to be displayed with the result (OK, or KO with the list of KO cams).

I've tried many solutions, found on this site, but none of those where successful (Threads, progressbar , dialog bar, Asynchronous task, etc.). Either I get exceptions, or the bar does not show, or the new Activity display before the completion of the process.

Could anyone help ? This is the relevant part of my code now:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

    // ON button
    Button myButton1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
    myButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            

        public void onClick(final View arg0) {

            intGoodCamera = 0;
            intBadCamera = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i<intNumCam; i++) {

                System.out.println (intStartingPortNb+i);

                String myurl = strIPAddress + ":" + (intStartingPortNb+i) + strSuffixSetAlarmOn;
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(myurl);
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {

                    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                    System.out.println (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) 
                        intGoodCamera++;
                    else {
                        intBadCamera++;
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            System.out.println ("OK: "+intGoodCamera + " KO: "+ intBadCamera);
            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Results.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(nextIntent);
        }
    });
```

.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)..

- Place starting **ProgressDialog** code in `onPreExecute()` of AsyncTask..
- Place your **HttpRequest** in `doInBackGround()` of AsyncTask.
- Now remove (dismiss) **ProgressDailog** in `onPostExecute()` and
  Start a new Activity in `onPostExecute()`.

Simple..

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that you put http requests in UI thread, which is forbidden since Android 3.0

I think you should check this link:
[httpGet Request error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056382/httpget-request-error/12056438#12056438)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading about AsyncTask.  Take a look at [this tutorial (http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#asynctask)](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#asynctask) for a good example of almost exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do operations which takes more than 5 seconds in UI thread.
For that Use [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

The call the next http request after the completion of the previous one (Since the task is running Async) and update the progress bar.

It is good to use a listener interface for handling the async task completion

Steps :

1. Call the async task to have first http request.
2. When the task completes, from the post execute section, write code to invoke its corresponding completion listener.
3. From completed listener, start the next http request and update the progress.
4. continue as long all the requests are made.