# Android Application Can not connet to web service

Tags: android

I am new to Android applications. The code that I am using is working on another computer which has Linux. But on my computer there is Windows 7 and the code is not working. It can not connect to webservice. Please help me.

Here is code:

```
package com.example.marport;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Giriscikis extends Activity {

    final static String NAMESPACE = "http://webservice.marport.dcat.com/";
    final static String METHOD_NAME = "gateOut";
    final static String METHOD_NAME2 = "gateIn";
    final static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://webservice.marport.dcat.com/gateOut";
    final static String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://webservice.marport.dcat.com/gateIn";
    final static String URL = "http://192.168.1.164:8070/test/services/MarportWebServicePort";

    private EditText cikis;
    private EditText giris;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.giriscikis);

        cikis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCikis);
        giris = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGiris);

        SoapObject Request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
        SoapObject Request2 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME2);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope2 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        soapEnvelope.dotNet = false;
        soapEnvelope2.dotNet = false;

        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
        soapEnvelope2.setOutputSoapObject(Request2);

        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION2, soapEnvelope2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            SoapPrimitive result=(SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            SoapPrimitive result2 = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope2.getResponse();
            giris.setText(result2.toString());
            cikis.setText(result.toString());
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here are the exceptions:

```
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.marport/com.example.marport.Giriscikis}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:144)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:76)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:146)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at com.example.marport.Giriscikis.onCreate(Giriscikis.java:53)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-24 08:25:40.928: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application force stop because..

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

**The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.**  Find much info on this [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

**Solution:**

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and put your network related operation in `doInVBackground()` of it..

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some network activity in that Activity on the Main UI thread. This will raise an exception whenever your build target is set to honeycomb or higher. To fix it move the Network operation to an AsyncTask.

Example :

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Result>{
                    private Activity activity;
                    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
                        super();
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Loading", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Result doInBackground(Void... v) {
        //do your stuff here
        return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Finished.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

Call it from the activity:

```
MyAsyncTask task = new AsyncTask(myActivity.this);
task.execute();
```

Comment: there is another code which i used async task.it is same with above code but still can not connect to webservice i think the problem is about windows but i do not know where is because same code is working on linux but is not working on windows

Comment: i also tried same code with async task but still can not connect to webservice

Comment: Did you write the <permissions> tag to connect your app on Internet?

Comment: yes used this code <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: does the app throw the same Exception when the web call is in an async task?

Comment: no there is different exception 08-24 09:08:22.048: E/AndroidRuntime(686): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to make an http request in the UI thread. Since Android 3.0 you have to put your request in another thread.

See that post : [HonyComb and DefaultHttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821845/honycomb-and-defaulthttpclient)

I also advice you to use try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by adding this after the setcontentview line:

```
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

I dont recommend it though, use AsyncTask if you have finished testing your code.

Comment: complier can not read Strict Mode trying to change as a strichmath

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the Windows 7 Firewall?

teaching grandma to suck eggs (which is sometimes helpful to grandmas) => http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-Windows-Firewall-on-or-off#

Comment: yes now windows 7 firewall is disable but stil can not connect to webservice

Comment: Can you get to the URL above using a browser? Just to confirm that the machine can route to that address...

Comment: machine is working well myfriends who have linux os is connecting to web service with same code

Comment: OK, so just to clarify that 'machine is working well' can you get to the URL in a browser on the Windows machine? Are the linux and windows machines on the same network?

Comment: yes ı get url from windows normally no problem linux and windows machines are on same network.

Comment: OK, does the Windows box have any other firewalling software installed? Maybe with the anti-virus?

Comment: no there is no anti-virus program or another firewalling software

Comment: Are the linux and windows machine Eclipse and Android SDK installs at the same level?

Comment: ok i solved problem the problem is i am working android 2.2 but emulators version is 4.1 so it makes problem