# Android minsdkversion and upload conflict in market

Tags: android, upload, admob, google-play

Hi guys i am facing the conflict between the target build and the minsdkversion. For using the admob latest version i have set the project build target to android 4.0 and when it is development i specified the minsdkversion as 8 and it worked fine. But when i tried to upload the application to google play market i got unable to process the apk file and after some research process in googling i changed the minsdktarget to 14 and then i was able to upload it to market. But the problem that i have i need to set the minsdktarget to 10. Please let me know how i can acheive this. I really need you peoples help on this. Hoping for better response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/) say that minSdkVersion is ***at least*** Android 1.5, so if you're using this library and don't want your app to crash (they won't be able to download it from Google Play) on older devices, you need to declare the minSdkVersion. You can set your targetSDKVersion to anything later than that.

For example:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Why do you have a need to set `minSdkVersion` to 10? In that case you can do:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: I want to minsdkversoin to 10 as i am facing the issue mentioned on this [posting] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821845/honycomb-and-defaulthttpclient)  And to overcome that i need to change it to 10 and also i want the application to be available for the peoples with android 2.3

Comment: Ok, then use the 2nd uses-sdk declaration in my answer.